# What's the difference with linkWithCredential and linkWithPopup

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I read the [Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)  and see that using the:

```
auth.currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential)
```

will merge the anonymous and e.g., Google, Facebook etc.. `credential`

Then I read [Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account Using JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) will do the same using the:

```
auth.currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider)
```

What is the difference and which should I use if my SPA Reactjs app require anonymous sign and later if user want to sign in he can do that with Google, Facebook..

I run some test and see that using `linkWithPopup` return error `auth/credential-already-in-use` if the Account exist so then I must use `signInWithCredential`. This works ok however so far.

Reading about `linkWithCredential` I don't see what to do if the Google account is already in use at Firebase. That `linkWithCredential` would create two account I don't think so I must maybe do what I did with `linkWithPopup` like `signInWithCredential`

This two does the same thing in the end; when to use what, or what did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[linkWithCredential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#linkwithcredential) links the account with credentials that you obtained from a previous sign-in.

[linkWithPopup()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#linkwithpopup) links the account with the given provider, guiding the user through the authentication flow for that provider.  The credentials will be automatically obtained from that sign-in.

So, if you already have credentials for an account where the user already signed in, use `linkWithCredential`.  If you don't have user credentials, and you need to user to go through a sign-in flow to get them, use `linkWithPopup()`.

The end result is the same in either case - the Firebase Auth account for the currently signed in will be linked to the other account (Google, Facebook, etc) where the user has proved their identity.

Answer (score 0):

`linkWithPopup()` is necessary for linking accounts on Flutter Web when the social auth would require a pop up. For instance, if you are needing to link an Apple account to an existing account, `signInWithPopup()` would authenticate, create a new firebase account and return the new user...which you don't want for an existing account.

With `linkWithPopup()`, you would authenticate the apple user and link, skipping the new account creation and return user steps.

If you use `signInWithPopup()` in conjunction with `linkWithCredential()`, you'll never reach `linkWithCredential()` in most cases (the user returns and rebuilds the app) or you'll just error on the link attempt because a new account had been created.